# Incorrect definition of table mysql.event after migrating database to mariadb

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mariadb, errors

I did a `mysqldump` to dump all databases into a `.sql` file, then installed a mariadb server. There are no errors after the installation. But after restoring the databases, I started to observe the following two errors:

> [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column
>   'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type
>   set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH'),
>   found type
>   set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_A
>   [ERROR] Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system
>   tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.

It looks like something within the `mysql.event` table got overwritten. I did not create any events, so I wasn't expecting anything to be affected here. What should be done to eliminate this error?

Comment: Did you run a `mysql_upgrade` after the installation?

Comment: @ypercube, no, I did not. It is a fresh installation.

Comment: I see 2 points in the [compatibility page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-versus-mysql-compatibility/) between MySQL and MariaDB that mention `'IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS'` and events. Both suggest running mysql_upgrade.

Comment: Which version of MySQL was the backup taken from and which MariaDB version did you install?

Comment: @ypercube, do you mean I just need to run that command? MariaDB is 5.5.34, same version as the MySQL.

Comment: Yes, see: [MariaDB: mysql_upgrade](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_upgrade/)

Comment: @ypercube, you are correct. I ran the command and it worked. Can you convert your comment to an answer? Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

On centos 7:

> mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.50-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

`mysql_upgrade -u root -p`

This issue is fixed.